# How to launch gradient animation on button tapped?

Tags: swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation, cagradientlayer

I'm creating an IOS application. I have 5 buttons in star shapes created with UIBezierPath. And I want fill them when I tapped specific star. For ex. if I tapped 3-rd star then gradient will fill 3 first stars etc.

I have already created view with 5 stars. In the draw view method I have added code for animating gradient and it works fine only when view is launched.

```
 override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        UIColor.black.setStroke()
        path.lineWidth = 2
        let numberOfPoints = 5
        var angle: CGFloat = CGFloat.pi / 2
        let angleOfIncrement = CGFloat.pi*2/CGFloat(numberOfPoints)
        let radius: CGFloat = rect.origin.x + rect.width/2
        let offset = CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x + rect.width/2, y: rect.origin.y + rect.height/2)
        let midleRadius = radius*0.45
        var firstStar = true


        for _ in 1...numberOfPoints {
            let firstPoint = getPointLocation(angle: angle, radius: midleRadius, offset: offset)
            let midlePoint = getPointLocation(angle: angle+angleOfIncrement/2, radius: radius, offset: offset)
            let secondPoint = getPointLocation(angle: angle+angleOfIncrement, radius: midleRadius, offset: offset)

            if firstStar {
                firstStar = false
                path.move(to: firstPoint)
                path.addLine(to: midlePoint)
                path.addLine(to: secondPoint)
            }else {
                path.addLine(to: firstPoint)
                path.addLine(to: midlePoint)
                path.addLine(to: secondPoint)
            }

            angle += angleOfIncrement

        }
        path.stroke()

            let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
            let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: layer)
            gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.white.cgColor]
            gradient.locations = [1]
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
            gradient.frame = path.bounds

            self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)

            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
            animation.fromValue = [0, 0]
            animation.toValue = [0, 1.0]
            animation.duration = 3
            gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)

            self.layer.mask = shapeLayer


    }
```

I expect that when I tapped 3-rd star then gradient will fill first 3 stars.

Comment: does calling draw after selecting a star work?

Comment: yes, but i have issue with animating after tapping on star.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate your drawing code from your animation code, and (btw.) you should also (re-)move the layer creation out of `draw()`.

For the separation move

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "locations")
animation.fromValue = [0, 0]
animation.toValue = [0, 1.0]
animation.duration = 3
gradient.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

into a separate method and call it when needed.

You must also remove the layer creation from `draw()`because this method is always called if the view needs to be (re-)drawn. This produce a serious memory leak, because for instance every rotation of your iPhone will create a new gradient layer.

You have another issue in your code. Your gradient layer lies over the layer of the view. That cannot work. You may make the gradient layer to the view's layer, and work with mask, to cut the stars out of the gradient.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough... There is a video that describes the situation https://youtu.be/1XpBn45PWSg. I want gradient fills stars. For ex. if I tapped 3-rd star then gradient will fill 3 first stars etc.